# Problema na re-execução do script em jQuery depois que é executado o mesmo evento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web em ASP.NET MVC e tenho algumas empresas cadastradas, criei um botão nesse grid que deixa a empresa ativa e inativa no sistema e estou criando um script jQuery para apagar as empresa e exibir-las novamente.

Meu problema é que quando clico no botão da empresa ele apague todo o conteúdo da `div #grid-elementos` excluindo todas as empresas, faz uma busca da lista de empresas e exibe para o usuário. Ocorre tudo normalmente porem depois do evento o uso do botão Ativo ou Inativo não reexecuta o script novamente.

Já tentei tanto usar o `$("#grid-elementos").empty()` como usar o `$("#grid-elementos").remove()` como tentei fazer as mesmas ações na `div $("#elemento")` ou como `$("#grid-elementos elemento")` mas ocorrem os mesmos problemas.

```
   <div id="grid-elementos">
           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
               <div id="elemento" class="Search">
                   <div id="campos-elemento">
                       <a href="/Empresa/EditEmpresa/@item.id_pessoa">
                           <div id="desc-elemento">
                               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
                           </div>
                           <div id="cod-elemento">
                               Cod.: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_pessoa)
                           </div>
                           <div id="cnpjcpf-elemento">
                               CNPJ.: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cpf_cnpj)
                           </div>
                       </a>
                   </div>
                   <div id="botoes-elemento">
                       <ul>                      
                           <li><button type="button" class="botao-elemento-ativo btn-status" data-item="@item.id_pessoa">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.situacao)</button></li>
                           <li><button type="button" class="botao-elemento-delete btn-delete" data-item="@item.id_pessoa">Deletar</button></li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
            }
       </div>
```

codigo jquery

```
       $(".btn-status").click(function () {
           var id = $(this).attr('data-item');
           alert(id);
           if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status do registro?")) {
               $.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "/Empresa/AlteraStatus/" + id,
                   success: function (data) {
                       $("#grid-elementos").empty();
                       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                           $("#grid-elementos").append(
                               "<div id=\"elemento\" class=\"Search\" >" +
                               "<div id=\"campos-elemento\" >" +
                               "<a href=\"/Empresa/EditEmpresa/" + item.id_pessoa + "\" >" +
                               "<div id=\"desc-elemento\" >" + item.nome +
                               "</div>" +
                               "<div id=\"cod-elemento\" >"
                               + "Cod.: " + item.id_pessoa +
                               "</div>" +
                               "<div id=\"cnpjcpf-elemento\" >"
                               + "CNPJ.: " + item.cpf_cnpj +
                               "</div>" +
                               "</a>" +
                               "</div>" +
                               "<div id=\"botoes-elemento\" >" +
                               "<ul>" +
                               "<li><button type=\"button\" class=\"botao-elemento-ativo btn-status\" data-item=\"" + item.id_pessoa + "\" >" + item.situacao + "</button></li>" +
                               "<li><button type=\"button\" class=\"botao-elemento-delete btn-delete\" data-item=\"" + item.id_pessoa + "\" >Deletar</button></li>" +
                               "</ul>" +
                               "</div>" +
                               "</div>"
                           );
                       });
                   },
                   error: function (data) {
                       alert("Houve um erro na pesquisa.");
                   }
               });
           }
       });
```

Estou me arriscando nesse projeto por conta própria porem sei muito pouco de programação em javascript como jQuery ou Ajax.

Comment: @RicardoPontual era isso mesmo e foi resolvido.

Comment: esse problema é um velho conhecido :)